# Deploying from OSX to Windows with Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

i just started developing mvc apps with monodevelop, and when i try to deploy to my hosting server, which is Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7, i can not get it to work, because some of the referenced libraries (Mono.Data.Sqlite, etc) are not published.

Does anyone had the same problem? How can i publish the mono libraries with the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to install mono . Just be sure that the libraries are included or project deploy (or copy them to project) or copy them to server's GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Your server will need to have mono installed too.

Comment: Well thats not acceptable at the moment, because my hosting services do not have mono on it.